# Initializing a static class member that depends on a private template type (C++)

Tags: c++, templates, static, private

I have the following situation:

```
class Test
{
private:
    class SubType
    {
    //...
    };
    static std::vector<SubType> v;
};
```

Because v is static, I initialize it in the cpp file with

```
std::vector<Test::SubType> Test::v;
```

But this does not work, the compiler tells me that "Test::SubType" is private.
What can I do about this?

Thanks!

Comment: In what context? At file-scope this should be fine.

Comment: Indeed, we may need more code.

Comment: it compiles fine on my system ... which compiler?

Comment: Can you post more code?  That snippet works for me with g++.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class A {
    class B {
    };
    static  B b;
    static vector <B> vb;
};

A::B A::b;
vector <A::B> A::vb;
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you forgot to `#include <vector>`. Because the following compiles on [comeau](http://www.comeaucomputing.com/tryitout/)

```
#include <vector>
class Test { 
    class SubType 
    { 
    //... 
    }; 
    static std::vector<SubType> v; 
};
std::vector<Test::SubType> Test::v;
```

Answer (score 0):

Others reported the code compiles fine. I want to supply the Standard wording for backing it up. At `11/5`

> All access controls in clause 11 affect the ability to access a class member name from a particular scope. The access control for names used in the definition of a class member that appears outside of the member’s class definition is done as if the entire member definition appeared in the scope of the member’s class. `[...]`
>
> [Example:
>
> ```
> class A {
>   typedef int I; // private member
>   I f();
>   friend I g(I);
>   static I x;
> };
>
> A::I A::f() { return 0; }
> A::I g(A::I p = A::x);
> A::I g(A::I p) { return 0; }
> A::I A::x = 0;
> ```
>
> Here, all the uses of `A::I` are well-formed because `A::f` and `A::x` are members of class A and g is a friend of class A. This implies, for example, that access checking on the first use of `A::I` must be deferred until it is determined that this use of `A::I` is as the return type of a member of class A. ]